# Amazon Web Services HTTP on custom port

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-security-group

I am trying to configure AWS Inbound security to allow HTTP on port 8384, but when I try to access the URL I still get the "Can't reach this page" message.

[image: I have attached my configuration below]

Comment: Some helpful resources for troubleshooting connectivity issues: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html and https://linuxacademy.com/blog/amazon-web-services-2/troubleshooting-ec2-connectivity-issues/

Comment: So your server is definitely listening to inbound traffic on port `8384`, and there isn't any firewall software on the server blocking that port?